# Changing a TreeViewItem template dpending upon the items object

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView bound to an observable collection of one type of object but I want to display a different DataTemplate based upon a value within that object rather than on the main object type because they are the same type. Further more and to clarify, I actually want to base it upon the type of object it contains.

```
Ok, so, rather than doing this:
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type listItem:TreeNodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding     Children}"
```

`I actually want to do this:`

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType.EmbeddedItem="{x:Type listItem:MyEmbededObjectType}"ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
```

`I have searched all day and now asking the question.`

Hello and thanks for your answer but I am still a little unsure what to do here. Also, I have just found out how to format the question so that it is all displayed and will make it easier to know what I am trying to do.
I am new to Wpf but a long time developer and because of that I am very quickly getting to grips with things but there are the odd thing that stumps me. I have a TreeView that displays a different template if the objects in the ObservableCollection are different objects but in this case the problem that in this case the objects are all of the same type in the ObservableCollection but each of these objects have an embedded object of a different type and that is what I am trying to get XAML to see as the object type in which to retrieve the template.
So, the objects I am providing in the ObservableCollection are TreeNodeViewModel. This class has an embedded object of type object called Item. It is the bound item that I use to know what the TreeNode is related to. This property is called Item and it is this property I want to use to lift up the template.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put both objects in your DataTemplate, and use an IValueConverter to set the Visibility.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Object1ShowThis" Visibility={StaticResource cMakeValueConverter/>
    <Button x:Name="Object2ShowThis" Visibility={StaticResource cMakeValueConverter2/>
   </StackPanel>
<DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This may be helpful but I do not fully understand the answer so I have updated my post with more information.